# String matching with tokenizing the key of a map

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a map in my Dynamo DB stored like this:

```
"A|1,2,3,4|B" : "[some data]"
"C|5,6|D" : "[some data]"
"X|7,8,9,10,11,12,13|Y" : "[some data]"
 ..
```

For the sake of discussion, let's say that each key in the above map is a concatenated result of three strings LEFT, MIDDLE AND RIGHT, as: "LEFT|MIDDLE|RIGHT".

I want to know if a given string is a key in the above map. However, the MIDDLE string should be split on the comma values for this match.
Example: Both "A|1|B" and "A|3|B" should match against the first entry. Similarly "C|5|D" matches the second entry and so on.

Assumptions: MIDDLE string can be a concatenation of 1 to 200 numbers(stored as strings). The map has about 35K entries.

I imagine that one straightforward way would be to "expand" the original map and break down each entry on the middle string to create multiple new key-value pairs with duplicate values. However, my data size is large and hence this approach would cost a lot of time and space complexity. Could there be an elegant way to solve this for a production environment?

Comment: could we assume that [some data] from the first row is not equal in general to [some data] in row two and three, etc?

Comment: Are "LEFT" and "RIGHT" always "A" and "B"?

Comment: How about a `trie` for the MIDDLE keys?

Comment: Is MIDDLE always a continuous interval of integers?

Comment: @Boris yes, "[some data]" is unique for all entries.

Comment: @Alexis no. But they are always one simple string value(you could assume them to be customer's first and last name), so I'm not much concerned about them. A and B are just placeholders.

Comment: @vivek_23 could you expand more, please?

Comment: @David yes, always. You could, for example, assume them to be the postal codes from where the customer last accessed your service.

Comment: @sircasms so `A` and `B` are always going to remain the same?

Comment: @vivek_23 no, they are first name and last names of a customer and will vary for different entries. Let me edit the question to eliminate confusion.

Comment: @sircasms is it possible that one key, say `23` can belong to more than 1 customer?

Comment: What do you want to retrieve? All matching lines or the first matching line?

Comment: @Each row is unique overall, but it is not guaranteed to have 23 belong to only one customer.

Comment: @Alexis Overall the keys are guaranteed to be unique. So, there will only be one match.

Comment: Ok, that changes everything. You better go with Boris Pavlović's solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would replace the MIDDLE with some random string, for example

```
"A|4806369425|B" : "[some data M]"
"A|0848833569|B" : "[some data N]"
"A|5514390566|B" : "[some data P]"
```

add another mapping

```
"1" : "4806369425"
"2" : "4806369425"
"3" : "4806369425"
"4" : "4806369425"
"5" : "0848833569"
"6" : "0848833569"
"7" : "5514390566"
"8" : "5514390566"
"9" : "5514390566"
...
"13" : "5514390566"
```

when fetching a value I would go to the second mapping finding the key for middle. it should be executed in O(1), then concatenate left and right and fetch some data from the first mapping again in O(1)

Comment: Just a note: A random string could be achieved using `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that (untested code):

```
String testString = "A|1,2,3,4|B"

String primarySeparator = "|";
String secondarySeparator = ",";

public boolean contains(String key) {
  String[] parts = testString.split(primarySeparator);
  List<String> values = Arrays.asList(parts[1].split(secondarySeparator)); // Point 1

  String[] keyParts = key.split(primarySeparator);

  if (keyParts[0].equals(parts[0])
    && keyParts[2].equals(parts[2]
    && values.contains(keyParts[1])) { // Point 2
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The line marked as "Point 1" splits the string using the "|" separator, selects the second value, which is your list of number, splits it using the "," separator and converts it as a list. So you get a list with all your the values you have in "MIDDLE".

Then, at the "Point 2", we test for matches.

Keep in mind that this code is untested and doesn't care about unexpected situations, like if your string has not the right amount of parts separated by "|" or if your list of values doesn't contains any value. You might want to tweak in order to take those cases into account.

If you want to test a large amount of lines, you should of course split your key only once.